# The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: angular

at the time I'm going to create component using ng g component command I facing with this error what I need to do to solve this.

"The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."

Comment: You should run it in folder with package.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your problem is from Angular/CLI version, Check Angular/CLI installed on your pc by the below code in CMD.

```
ng version
```

[image]

The latest version is 7.1.2. If your version is lower than this version,
please use:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

to get the latest version and update the last packages which you used in your project by [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates).

Otherwise, probably your problem is from file angular.json config.

Answer (score 7):

1. Check you are in correct project or not.
2. Check **angular.json** file in your project first,if it is missing,add file.
3. Update angular CLI.

Answer (score 6):

If you trying to add new component to an existing project, you should install packages on your system first.

run this code on your console at your root project folder:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 5):

Your project folder must either contain `angular.json` or `angular-cli.json`.

The above mentioned file contains your project definition and its structure. So, that's why without these files and without `angular-cli` installed. You won't be able to run,
`ng g component` command successfully.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get this behavior if you are confusing ng new  with ng g application .

Comment: Yes, `ng new` first... why doesn't the documentation for `ng generate` mention this "detail"?

Answer (score 2):

first

`cd "project name"`

then

`ng serve` or `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

After ng new project make sure you entered project directory in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

first you check whether you are in workspace location or in your angular-application location.
If you are in workspace location then type in command prompt

> \workspace>cd angular-application

now you are in following location
**\workspace\angular-application>**
here you type ng serve then your application compile and build

> \workspace\angular-application>ng serve

you getting below information

> C:\Users\venkat\Documents\angular\myfirstangular>ng serve --port 4300

Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4300, open your browser on http://localhost:4300/ 
 95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /

### Date: 2019-02-12T18:15:21.157Z

chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.75 MB [initial] [rendered]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add fire npm install command in your root directory of project then npm start.
it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to project folder and execute command again

Answer (score 0):

Run ng serve command in client folder